# How does hawking radiation work without virtual particles?

Tags: black-hole, quasars, hawking-radiation

How does hawking radiation work without the existence for virtual particles? I read that certain quantum fields are distorted when a black hole forms on top of them. But what fields specifically? If hawking radiation is thermal radiation then it should be the photon field that is distorted, right?